# Using Qt animation framework for custom delegate in a QListView

Tags: c++, qt, animation, delegates

I would like to add an effect of moving rows, like a store, in a QListView using QAnimation.
I use a custom delegate to render things from a QStandardItemModel.
My delegate is a custom widget.

The paint method in the delegate creates the widget, paints it and destroys it. I have no direct access to each custom widget displayed.
Nevertheless, I would like to use setPos() within the animation to move this "not accessible" widget.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: You don't have the pointer to the QWidget, right?

Comment: No, the widget is destroy after the paint().

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you want to achieve is not very clear.
Have you thought of moving the animation into the QListView? 
It should have visibility of all items in it's model.